# How to disable field on register form but keep show in edit profile?

Tags: users

I need to know how to disable field on register form but keep show in edit profile? because now if I can only enable in both section, edit profile / register.

I need only show username + email field on register, but custom a lot of custom field on edit profile. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Drupal 7

In D7 you can edit each user field under `Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage Fields` and untick the option **Display on user registration form**.

### Drupal 8

In D8 after you add your fields under `Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage Fields` go to  `Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage form display`, scroll down and uncollapse **Custom display settings**, tick the **Register** option and Save.

Now you will see two sub-tabs on that page: `Default` and `Register`. Visit the **Register** sub-tab and rearrange the fields to disable the ones you don't want. This will apply to the Registration form only.

The `Default` settings will apply to the User Edit form, so you'll want to keep the field enabled there.